# Which Activity gets called when i start a application?

Tags: android

I was going through my android beginners tutorials and I m not able to understand which activity is called when the app is started.

Comment: Look here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html#launching-activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by which `Activity` is called ? This question may closed soon, But for your info, *The `Activity` having these two attributes in `Manifest.xml` is the first `Activity` to be launched in the app.*

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Not exactly. Only LAUNCHER is enough (i.e.: if you have a SplasScreen, this Activity will be the LAUNCHER, but the MAIN Activity will have the DEFAULT attribute). If (let's say, 90% of the cases) your LAUNCHER is the MAIN Activity, then you are right. +1 for covering 9/10 (approx) of the cases

Comment: Thank you very much sir... Your guidelines will be path for us to walk. I really appreciate your suggestion...